# "Marry something with something" - is this idiom often used in America?

Tags: idioms

I saw this unfamiliar idiom 'marry something with' when I was searching about the words 'combining' and 'associating' on Google. While writing my english self introduction, I really wanted to find more appropriate word in the context.

Here's [a link](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/marry).
In the site, it's said:

> 4 [transitive] (also marry up) *formal* to combine two different ideas, designs, tastes etc together
>   **marry something with/to something**
>
> > The building’s design marries a traditional style with modern materials.
>
> **marry something and something**
>
> > He writes fiction that marries up realism and the supernatural.

Is it often used in America and am I ok to use this idiom like this sentence?

> 'I can be creative and think about new cities while marrying my humane? and artistic imagination with various disciplines such as urban planning.'

My self introduction is based on my dream (Urban planning). My interests are liberal arts and urban planning. P.S: I love fancy words and phrases. Plus, can anyone advise any kinds of dictom or maxim and what is the difference between 'apparatus' and 'brainchild'?

Please give me advice and correct my sentence:) Also, give me examples with details. I would be really thankful. :)

Comment: Suggestion:  Learn what a "paragraph" is.

Comment: (And my impression is that using "marry" in this sense is more British than American.)

Comment: As regards "apparatus" and "brainchild" - have you tried looking in a dictionary?

Comment: If your question is "Is this idiom often used / easily understood?" then that's an acceptable question on this site. If it's "Is this sentence ok?" - then that's not what this site is about.

Answer (score 2):

I think "marry" doesn't work in this context because the marriage metaphor involves exactly two distinct and seperate individuals. You've got a list of things which are getting "married" to each other, some of which are already closely related (aspects of your imagination), and these both break the metaphor. You could just say "combining".

Save "marry" for when there are two things which are not usually combined.

Comment: I also think that “marry” should be used for when the union persists in some product.  A book marrying fiction and the supernatural persists. The building marrying different design concepts persists. But being creative is not persistent.  The **outcome** of the creative thinking session may be something that marries two disciplines.

Comment: @Jim good point

Comment: Thank you for your specific answers. :) I really appreciated.